# Returning my borrowed iPad to work: how to clear of all personal apps/data

Tags: ipad

I have an iPad (2?) that is on loan from work. I'm about to leave the company that I work for so need to return the iPad. However before I do so I want to delete all the personal apps and data that I put on the iPad.

How can I make sure I return a clean iPad and what hidden files should I look out for?

The other question I have is: I understand that I'll be getting a new iPad at my next firm, but this won't happen until I've left my current workplace. Is there any way I can 'migrate' the stuff I've got on my current iPad, onto the new one, via my Apple ID?

Thanks in anticipation!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the MDM (Mobile Device Management) but you can wipe the iPad by following these steps:

1. Go to **Setting**
2. Go to General and (for iPads on the right) swipe down, tap on **Reset**.
3. Then tap on **Reset all content and settings**.

Your Apple ID will save all app's and when you log in your new iPad it will migrate some stuff. Again, depending on MDM your iCloud might have been turned off.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much for your prompt and straightforward answer. I'm pleased it's that easy!

Comment: Hi @Poll, you're welcome. Please be so kind to check this answer as correct by clicking on the 'check' icon under the arrows on the top left of my answer.